# How to remove old problematic git commits

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history

Recently we found two old git commit from one of our ex team member, which is malicious and affected our entire repository. First commit deleted all files from repository and second commit added all the files back to the repository. Because of that, there is no changes on codebase and it took us couple of days to notice.

The commit is couple of weeks old and in the mean time we have more than 100 new commits by other team members and 10/15 merges between different branches. Now is it possible to entirely remove that commit from the git repo?

One option we thought of is rebasing but because of merging and merge conflict we are finding it very difficult. What should be best course of action to resolve this issue?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/undo-revert-old-commit

Comment: A commit that deletes everything followed immediately by a commit that restores everything exactly as it was has no effect on *using* the repository. You're probably best off leaving it in, provided it really does restore everything exactly as it was.

Comment: To delete the adjacent commits, use `git replace` followed by `git filter-branch` or `git filter-repo`. Note that the resulting repository *replaces* the old repository: everyone must switch over to using the new repository and stop using all their existing clones. That's why it's probably best to just leave it in.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention that the two commits did not bring any changes to the codebase, you could do something as simple as creating a new branch from a commit prior to the two malicious commits, and you could then cherry-pick the rest of the history from the main branch.

Let's say you have a git history on `main` that looks like this:

```
6259e6d (master) Fifth commit
d96e3a7 Fourth commit
192ec1a Third commit # malicious commit 
254d6e0 Second commit # malicious commit
ed55fff First commit
```

then you can:

```
# 1. Identify the commit before the first malicious commit and create a branch off it
$ git branch clean_branch ed55fff

# 2. Checkout the new branch
$ git checkout clean_branch

# 3. Cherry-pick changes from the main branch
$ git cherry-pick d96e3a7^..6259e6d
```

The git history of the new branch (`clean_branch`) will now not include the two commits you wanted to remove:

```
$ git log --oneline
a195fe0 Fifth commit
3e52330 Fourth commit
ed55fff First commit
```

you now have a branch with clean history; you can now make this branch the new `main`

Comment: That is also a potential solution for us. The only problem is there are 100+ commits after that. Cherry picking all the commits one by one will be tiresome. Do you have a solution to make it automated or in batch?

Comment: @AliHasanImam You only need to run `git cherry-pick` once; as shown in my answer, `git cherry-pick` can take a range of commits

Comment: Sorry, missed that one. Thanks, will check it.

Comment: @AliHasanImam Cool, let me know